# How to prevent .on('click') function working for a link in a table row

Tags: jquery

I have a table that, when a row is clicked on that row's textboxes and buttons show and its labels hide. I've now added a link in the last column that I need to function normally, but **not** cause the row to got into "edit" mode, but only when the link itself is clicked.

Here's the code for a row:

```
<tr class="viewEditRow rowBorder" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <td class="deleteBranch">
        <input type="checkbox" class="chkDeleteBranch" name="deleteBranches[]" value="1"><br>
        <input type="submit" class="cancelListEditBranch edit hideOnLoad" value="Cancel" title="Cancel editing this branch"><br>
        <input type="submit" class="submitListEditBranch edit hideOnLoad" value="Save" title="Save the changes">
    </td>
    <td class="viewEditBranchName">
        <label class="viewBranchName detailDisplay">Atlanta</label>
        <input type="text" class="edit editBox editName hideOnLoad" value="Atlanta"><br>
        <br>
        <label id="lblBranchesListEditError" class="errorMsg"></label>
    </td>
    <td class="viewEditBranchUrl">
        <label class="viewBranchUrl detailDisplay"><a href="http://whub32.webhostinghub.com/~forsyt11/index.php/coverage-area/georgia" class="branchDetailLink" title="Click to go the branch's web page">georgia</a></label>
        <input type="text" class="edit editBox editUrl hideOnLoad" value="georgia">
    </td>
</tr>
```

This code hides the labels and shows the textboxes and buttons when that row is clicked on.

```
$('#tblViewEditAllBranches').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
        $(this).find('.editBox').val($(this).find('.detailDisplay').text());
    });

    // Hide edit elements in other rows and labels in clicked row
    $('#tblViewEditAllBranches tr').not(this).find('.edit').fadeOut(200);
    $('label', this).fadeOut(200);

    // Show labels in other rows and edit elements in clicked row
    $('#tblViewEditAllBranches tr').not(this).find('label').delay(200).fadeIn(200);
    $('.edit', this).delay(200).fadeIn(200);

    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

What's currently happening is, when the link in the last column is clicked on, the row goes into "edit" mode **and** the browser loads the url that was clicked on.

I need to allow the link to work, but when the link - and *only* the link - is clicked on, the row does **not** go into edit mode, but loads the url.

I've tried the following code to try to accomplish this, but the closest I got was when I used return false, which wasn't really "close" at all, since it didn't follow the url, but the row did go into edit mode. e.preventDefault and e.stopPropagation both don't seem to have any effect.

```
$('#tblViewEditAllBranches tr').find('label.viewBranchUrl').on('click', 'a.branchDetailLink', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
});
```

Comment: `return false;` wont work?

Comment: @JonathandeM., please re-read the last paragraph...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap you function in a condition that check if closest clicked element is the link.

Try this code:

```
$('#tblViewEditAllBranches').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
    if($(e.target).closest('a.branchDetailLink').length == 0){
        $(this).find('td').each(function() {
            $(this).find('.editBox').val($(this).find('.detailDisplay').text());
        });

        // Hide edit elements in other rows and labels in clicked row
        $('#tblViewEditAllBranches tr').not(this).find('.edit').fadeOut(200);
        $('label', this).fadeOut(200);

        // Show labels in other rows and edit elements in clicked row
        $('#tblViewEditAllBranches tr').not(this).find('label').delay(200).fadeIn(200);
        $('.edit', this).delay(200).fadeIn(200);

        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/78d4z/

Comment: Upon seeing your suggestion, I thought that was a great idea - check if what is being clicked should be "ignored", and it does work in the jsFiddle, but unfortunately it doesn't in my own code.

Comment: Turns out this was the solution. It didn't work the first time I tried it because I still had the stopPropagation line on the anchor click event. Once I removed that, everything worked as needed! Thanks!

Comment: Great! Happy to see it's helped you

Answer (score 0):

either do

```
return false;
```

or

[**`e.stopPropagation();`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

`console.log` might come in handy for debugging this

`event.stopPropagation` prevents the event from bubbling from the anchor that was clicked to it's parents, such as the table row.

Comment: If you read my question completely, you'd see that I did try everything you mentioned...

Comment: You edited your question, `return false;` wasn't mentioned previously

Comment: Sorry - that was late last night - I didn't remember that I added that afterwards. I've tried your and Code-Source's suggestions, but nothing's worked. I also did some messing around with selectors, drilling down to clicking on each td, but nothing either - although I'm not the best at figuring out accurate selectors, either...

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly, it's a question of how the event handler is attached.

Something like this should exclude the unwanted event handling :

```
$('#tblViewEditAllBranches').on('focus', 'label', function(e) {
    // ...
    //your existing code here
    // ...
});
```

You may need to play around with this a bit - it depends on exactly what you want.

You could, for example, attach the handler to every cell except the last one in each row.